# IEqualityComparer(of object) for Intersect or Except not working

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics

`enter code here`Want to remove items from a Main list , but give an error 'Unable to cast object of type `<ExceptIterator>d__99'1[`'

```
    Public Class FieldCollectionItemCompare
    Implements System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer(Of FieldCollectionItem)

    Public Shadows Function Equals(ByVal x As FieldCollectionItem, ByVal y As FieldCollectionItem) As Boolean Implements System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer(Of FieldCollectionItem).Equals

        If x.UniqueID = y.UniqueID Then
            Equals = True
        Else
            Equals = False
        End If
    End Function

    Public Overloads Function GetHashCode(ByVal obj As FieldCollectionItem) As Integer Implements System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer(Of FieldCollectionItem).GetHashCode
        GetHashCode = obj.UniqueID + obj.UniqueID
    End Function

    End Class
```

...here is what I am doing

```
FieldCollectionToProcessList = FieldCollectionToProcessList.Intersect(FieldCollectionRejected, New FieldCollectionItemCompare)

FieldCollectionToProcessList = FieldCollectionToProcessList.Intersect(FieldCollectionAccepted, New FieldCollectionItemCompare)
```

...all the list are  `As Generic.List(Of FieldCollectionItem)`

Comment: do i need to check if any of comparing list count is empty or not ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to assign the result of `Intersect` back to `FieldCollectionToProcessList`. The result isn't a `List(Of FieldCollectionItem)` - it's an `IEnumerable(Of FieldCollectionItem)`. You'll need to call `ToList` if you need to turn it back into a list. You could do it all in one step though:

```
// Variable names changed for sanity
list = list.Intersect(rejected, New FieldCollectionItemCompare).
            Intersect(accepted, New FieldCollectionItemCompare).
            ToList
```

Note that if you have Option Strict on, you should be able to see the error at compile time.

You might also want to consider creating a `HashSet(Of FieldCollectionItem)`, then use [`IntersectWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb293080.aspx).

None of this has anything to do with your custom equality comparer, although I note that you could just use:

```
Return x.UniqueID = y.UniqueID
```

for `Equals`, and

```
Return obj.UniqueID
```

for `GetHashCode`.